# npm install ngx-contextmenu @angular/cdk not working on angular 11

Tags: angular

I created project using "ng new proj". Below is the package.json file created. ng serve is also working fine. When i run npm install ngx-contextmenu @angular/cdk, its failing with below error. Can someone please suggest how to fix below error, based on error, i tried to go with @angular/common@12, but its giving problem in some other module etc.

```
npm install ngx-contextmenu @angular/cdk
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: proj@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~11.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
     "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of `@angular/cdk`requires which you try to fetch by ommiting required version, requires `@angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0"` while you have locked that dependency to major version 11 via`"@angular/common": "~11.0.6",`

Either specify lower version of `cdk` or upgrade all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a version that depends to Angular 12

You have to install the sdk compatibile with the correct Angular Version (I can see you are using Angular 11).

Try

```
 npm install ngx-contextmenu@5.4.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried and i got below error: ``` npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! While resolving: proj@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~11.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@9.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@">=6.0.0 <10.0.0" from ngx-contextmenu@5.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-contextmenu
npm ERR!     ngx-contextmenu@"5.4.0" from the root project
 
 ```

Comment: Can you please let me know where i can find the modules compatible with angular 11.

Comment: Hi vrreddy1234, can you upload your code to Stackblitzs? There are two possible solutions as Antoniosssss said. First, you could update your project to Angular 12, and second, you could fix its dependencies.

If you upload your code to stackblitz, I can try to make it work, and show you how I did it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-klmg8p  I just put the package.json contents and its updating. I have to run npm install ngx-contextmenu @angular/cdk